# Command java works in interactive shell but not in shell script

Tags: java, shell, sh

I wrote a really simple script with only one command and this one is working in the interactive shell but not in a script.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "--- Running game ---"
java -cp lib/java-json.jar:bin:. com.theaigames.game.warlight2.Warlight2 "../example-map.txt" "java -cp bot.BotStarter" "java -cp bot.BotStarter" 2>err.txt 1>out.txt
```

When I display the content of err.txt after executing the script I get this :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com.theaigames.game.warlight2.Warlight2
```

But when I use it in an interactive shell the program is executed :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/JSONException
at com.theaigames.game.warlight2.Warlight2.setupGame(Warlight2.java:91)
at com.theaigames.engine.Engine.start(Engine.java:89)
at com.theaigames.game.warlight2.Warlight2.main(Warlight2.java:293)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.JSONException
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 3 more
```

(The java error isn't the problem here)

Comment: Check the environment for differences, like the class path or the current working directory. Oh, btw, the "linux" tag was misapplied (see its description!) and the subject is also a bit misleading, the `java` program works fine in both situations, it's what is going on inside which isn't.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Indeed as answered below it's a problem about the current directory. I still don't understand why the output is different while I'm in the same directory when executing the script or the command.

Answer (score 1):

It might cause by **current working directory** path. You can make sure by using `-Duser.dir` JVM argument.

Or, you can change the path before executing java.

```
#!/bin/sh
cd <your dir>
java <some arguments>
```

Comment: I've just added this before executing.

`if [! -d "bin" ]; then
    cd $HOME/Documents/IA/Project/warlight2-engine-master/bin
fi`
In my project there are three directories (bin, src, lib). The script is bin. Now when I execute the program while I'm in the project folder it works but if I'm not it's not working.